# How to compare 2 multiply imputed nested Cox proportional hazards models?

Tags: survival, cox-model, likelihood-ratio, multiple-imputation, nested-models

I've got 2 nested Cox models, which I fit to 10 imputed datasets. Pooling the regression coefficient estimates and associated p-values I've done already.

I'm trying to work out if adding one extra predictor improves the model significantly. This is trivial for a Cox model without imputed data, using anova.coxph.

What I'd like to do is instead is assess whether the model is better 'across the imputed datasets', if that makes sense - so a kind of pooling of the likelihood ratio tests. I know you can do this for linear or logistic models using the D3 function in the mice package. However, I've got no idea if you'd be allowed to do this for nested, imputed COX models.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?